# how to calculate number of user in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to calculate the number of users like this in SQL.

```
select count(*) as nbr_users from users
```

How can I do the same thing in mongodb?

Comment: I don't get how your question relates to your description

Comment: @KevinSmith sorry is just an error

Answer (score 1):

```
db.nbr_users.count()
```

Check out the SQL-Comparision on MongoDB website, It has all the common select statements converted to MongoDB queries -
 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/#select